# Finding exponent of the number 10

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Finding exponent of the number 10 in 100! .

Now , some explains in my book show this.
[image]

So , it says that expel the of 5 and 10 are same but in my other book where there is a Q to Finding exponent of the number 10 in 100!.

Answer for 5 is 24 and for 10 is 11. Why is that ?

Comment: $100!$ has in it the factors $5,10,15,20,25,30,\dots,95,100$.  It is worth noting further that $25,50,75,100$ each contribute two factors of $5$ while the others contribute one factor of five...  So, we have $\lfloor\frac{100}{5}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{100}{5^2}\rfloor = 20+4=24$ factors of $5$ present in the overall product in $100!$.  There are many more factors of $2$ than there are of $5$, there being well over $50$ (*seen easily by only counting each even number once rather than multiple times if divisible by $4$ or higher*)

Comment: "*Answer...for 10 is 11*"  I have no idea what you are talking about here with that.

Comment: Exponent of 10 in 100! Is 11.@JMoravitz but in another textbook of mine .

Comment: Why would we ever choose to leave $10$ as a term to have an exponent of in a factorization of a factorial... changing $20$ into $2\times 10$ and $30$ into $3\times 10$ rather than changing $10$ into $2\times 5$ and $20$ into $2^2\times 5$, $30$ into $2\times 3\times 5$ etc...?  Absurd

Comment: @JMoravitz I think the textbook wrong now. Thanks

Comment: I mean... you *could* say that $20! = 10^2\times 2\times (1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdots \cdot 9\cdot 11\cdot 12\cdots 19)$... but that is a silly question to ask.  The proper question to be asking is "*what is the highest exponent of $10$ which divides $100!$*" or "*what is the exponent of $5$ in the prime factorization of $100!$*"... not "*what is the exponent of $10$ in some arbitrarily contrived factorization of $100!$ which doesn't even try to maximize the exponent*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$100! =$

```
9332621544394415268169923885626670049071596826438162146859296389521759999322991
5608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

which has $24$ zeros at the end.  There are more $2$s than $5$s and so the number of $5$s determines the number of $10$s.

Arguing there are just eleven $10$s would be like saying the $5!$ is not a multiple of $10$. But since it is $120$ there is clearly one $10$ which come from the $5$ and an earlier $2$.

Comment: Thanks. Got it .